# Temporary Files Still Appearing in Current Dir

Tags: auto-save

I have this in my .init.el file:

```
(setq backup-directory-alist
      `((".*" . "~/.saves")))
(setq auto-save-file-name-transforms
      `((".*" "~/.saves" t)))
```

Yet I am still getting random backup files in both the working directory and my home directory.

How can I fix this? Is there another setting I'm missing?

Comment: Try not have `~` in the path, instead use the full path. (I don't know if this is needed, but I have it in my init file, there must have been a reason for it.) Also, make sure the auto-save directory exists.

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but they are still being created. The .save directory is there and I changed it to the full user path.

Comment: The documentation for backup-directory-alist says "On MS-DOS filesystems without long names this variable is always ignored." Do you use an Emacs that is compiled as an MS-DOS application?

Answer (score 1):

Try without the star in `backup-directory-alist` and add slash at the end of directory name

```el
 (setq backup-directory-alist
        '(("." . "~/.saves/"))) ;; remove the star
 (setq auto-save-file-name-transforms
        `((".*" ,"~/.saves/" t)))
```

Comment: Ahhhh, never mind still happening. Is it weird that they are appearing in the $HOME directory?